# template return when Element is a struct

Tags: c++

So as the title states I have this problem. I'm implementing a Doubly Linked List as a template and on some of the functions like

```
Element getFirst();
Element getLast();
Element getPosition(int position);
```

They are supposed to return an element of type Element. The problem is, what if the list is empty? What do I return then? I can't return 0 or some integer because what if my Element is a struct. It will crash later in the code. What should my return be then? 
I tried creating an empty variable of type Element and sending it but this doesn't work either. 
Any ideas?

I can provide any piece of code you need, or information. Just ask

Comment: You may throw an exception when trying to retrieve elements from an empty list

Comment: Can you modify the interface?

Comment: My code is not built on exceptions. It's something fast made, I need to return something

Comment: You might get used to the concept of iterators (where you can express an empty range)

Comment: @Charlotte45 `The problem is, what if the list is empty?`  Isn't that what you should have been thinking of at design time?  It isn't a good thing writing code, and then finding out you've painted yourself into a corner.  If `Element` has some property that can be queried for `good` or `bad`, then maybe set it to `bad` so that the caller can test it.  Isn't the greatest thing, but that's one option.

Comment: I've been sending off a 0 up until now. I mean.. when list is empty, I was sending a 0 and that was ok until I tried to use my list with structs, that's when it failed.

Comment: @Charlotte45 But even your original design of returning 0 is bad.  A linked list of integers -- what if 0 is a valid item in the list?

Comment: Yea, I know it was bad. It was not meant to be used in a company or anything. It was just something fast for a project that had to be done and now it's turning up on me

Comment: @Charlotte45 Well, lesson learned I guess.  Always anticipate what may happen -- don't go for the "easy" way out if you can help it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution depends on you:

1. Have undefined behaviour if a function is called on an empty container. You should document these cases clearly. In such a case the user would have to check if the call to a function would be valid via for example an `empty` method. This is the case for [`std::vector::front`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/front).
2. Throw an exception like [`std::vector::at`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at) does.
3. Return [`boost::optional`](http://www.boost.org/libs/optional) as descriped in the other answer
4. Return a pointer or an iterator like suggested in the comments
5. Since you are not returning references to the elements you could also return a default constructed object of type `T`, which ideally would have a way to check that it is invalid. Similar to what [`QHash::value`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qhash.html#value) does.

In either case you have to do checks somewhere in your code.

Comment: Similar to 3. return a pointer (as I suppose that the Element exits in OP container and no copy were needed).

Comment: I tried including the library fost optional and the program wont recognize it. #include "optional/optional.hpp" this is what I tried

Comment: @Jarod42 thanks for the tipp, I added it to the answer including iterators.

Comment: @Charlotte45 You need to have boost installed on your system. Moreover you need to inform your build system of boost, this depends on what you use to build your program.

Comment: Oww oook I understand.

Comment: @mat69 How would returning a pointer would work here? I find that the most viable solution at the moment if only I knew how it works

Comment: @Charlotte45 You would check if the object is in the container and if it is return a pointer to it, otherwise you would return `nullptr`. This would mean that you have to check on use if you actually got a value. E.g. `Element *elmen = obj.getFirst(); if(elemn) { /* do something */}`

Answer (score 2):

Use [`boost::optional`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html). You would change the return type to be `boost::optional<Element>`. `boost::optional` is [contextually convertible to `bool`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_cast). So, an example use would be:

```
if(yourList.getFirst())
  std::cout << "Found the first element." << std::endl;
else
  std::cout << "No first element exists." << std::endl;
```

Under the hood, `boost::optional<T>` maintains a `bool` indicating whether or not the object has been initialized with a valid `T`. The default constructor creates an `optional<T>` object marked as not having a valid `T`.

Comment: Hmm I'll check out how optional can be used. First time I hear about it. Is it something like auto? I can't use the cout part cause I'm trying to implement a data structure which I'll later on use it to solve a problem

Comment: Or maybe simply `Element*`

Comment: as an example: if you change your return type to `boost::optional<int>`, you can return an `int` like if you were normally returning an `int` or return `boost::none` which means the return value is empty.

Comment: @Jarod42 can you get more into detail on how a pointer would work in this situation?

Answer (score 2):

There are several options:

- Provide a query method to see if the object can support the op (e.g., `empty`).
- Return something that can signify "empty". E.g., you can return a (const) pointer, or [`optional<Element>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/optional).

A different approach, which would work but should be avoided, is to throw an exception.